How can i display a excel file info related to a user with his earnings when they login to their dashboard on wordpress
Im developing a invesment platform with wordpress in where the users when they login using the plugin Paid Memberhship Pro, and i want when the user logs in to their dashboard they can see how much they have invested and how much they have earned (all of this info is in a excel drive on onedrive) and i want to display this information per user.
Best Regards
I tried using a plugin called wpDataTable, but it displays the info to all of the users all of the earnings, so i can see everybodys earnings and info, i want to display the info per user.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
